# SSRS IIF statement from another expression example

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, reporting

I have an expression which is written in a Crystal Reports calculated field as follows:

```
if {SERVICE_POINTS.CODE} in ["MIDRO", "MID3F", "MID5C", "MIDAC", "MIDBL", "MIDBM", "MIDDA","MIDCO", "MIDSW", "MIDBV",  "MIDHV", "MIDNV", "MIDSV", "TEABV", "MIDHB"] then "MIDWIFERY LED"  
 else if {SERVICE_POINTS.CODE} in ["RAADP", "MIDAO", "MIDBC", "MIDLB", "MIDLA","MIDNB","CONC1", "CONC2", "TEAAI", "TEBDJ", "TECCI", "TEDBJ", "MIDBF"] then "NURSE LED"   
else if {SERVICE_POINTS.CODE} in ["BOMCB", "THOCA", "THOGY", "THOGT"] then "ANAES" 
ELSE ""Check MDR""Check MDR""
```

Now I am trying to replicate the same formula in SSRS and came up with the following code:

```
IIF(SERVICE_POINTS_CODE.Value IN ["MIDRO", "MID3F", "MID5C", "MIDAC", "MIDBL", "MIDBM", "MIDDA","MIDCO", "MIDSW", "MIDBV",  "MIDHV", "MIDNV", "MIDSV", "TEABV", "MIDHB"] ,"MIDWIFERY LED",  
IIF(SERVICE_POINTS_CODE.Value IN  ["RAADP", "MIDAO", "MIDBC", "MIDLB", "MIDLA","MIDNB","CONC1", "CONC2", "TEAAI", "TEBDJ", "TECCI", "TEDBJ", "MIDBF"], "NURSE LED" ,  
IIf (SERVICE_POINTS.CODE in ["BOMCB", "THOCA", "THOGY", "THOGT"] ,"ANAES" ,"Check MDR""Check MDR")))
```

But the above code is giving me errors. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Please use the correct tags,`Crystal Reports` is not `VB.NET` even if the syntax does look similar in places, so edit your question to remove the `VB.NET` tag. Please format your code correctly in the question for readability. And lastly please include the error message as without that we are just guessing. I appreciate you are new so please take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and have a look at [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks,

Comment: In the last IIF statement, the False part has 2 values of "Check MDR""Check MDR". I think this is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `IndexOf` function:

```
=Switch(
Array.IndexOf(Split( "MIDRO,MID3F,MID5C,MIDAC,MIDBL,MIDBM,MIDDA,MIDCO,MIDSW,MIDBV,MIDHV,MIDNV,MIDSV,TEABV,MIDHB" , ","), Fields!SERVICE_POINTS_CODE.Value)>-1 ,"MIDWIFERY LED",
Array.IndexOf(Split( "RAADP,MIDAO,MIDBC,MIDLB,MIDLA,MIDNB,CONC1,CONC2,TEAAI,TEBDJ,TECCI,TEDBJ,MIDBF" , ","), Fields!SERVICE_POINTS_CODE.Value)>-1 ,"NURSE LED",
Array.IndexOf(Split( "BOMCB,THOCA,THOGY,THOGT" , ","), Fields!SERVICE_POINTS_CODE.Value)>-1,"ANAES",
true,"Check MDR"
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot alejandro that works . any tutorial link where i can better understand the iff and switch for multiple cases . I am using vb for the first time so having a hard time . thanks again

Comment: @DeveshSharma, SSRS expression is a [subset of VB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx), however you can use VB code in [custom functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx). If my answer solved your issue you can mark it as the correct answer, check [how to do it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).